# reactjs display state information

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to use react context in one of my project. Part of the below, I'm trying to display the state information once the state is updated ie; function confirmFavourites is called.

```
export class AppProvider extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            page: 'dashboard',
            ...this.savedSettings(),
            setPage: this.setPage,
            confirmFavorites: this.confirmFavorites
        }
    }

    confirmFavorites = () => {        
        this.setState({
            firstVisit: false,
            page: 'dashboard'
        })

        localStorage.setItem('cryptoDash', JSON.stringify({
            'test': 'hello'
        }))
        console.log('Hello1 -', this.state)
    }
```

When I view the state information in the logs, I don't see the firstVisit variable being displayed.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add that property when initializing the state object, then update accordingly.

```
         this.state = {
            page: 'dashboard',
            ...this.savedSettings(),
            setPage: this.setPage,
            firstVisit: false,
            confirmFavorites: this.confirmFavorites
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, That worked, should every attribute defined earlier?

Comment: It is always recommend to initialize all the component's variables in constructor for optimization and better performance.